# Display the article in the database base on categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a database with a table to stock the products of my site and the table has the following column for all the categories a specific product belongs to:
[image: Column of the table for products]

After making a query to get the categories the first row belongs to, The information is stored in an object which looks like this `$productDetails->ProductCategoryID` and the content is the following: `dinner,casual,kids`

Now,my question is that how can I use the SQL command `SELECT` to get all the products having at least one category in common by using `PHP`.

Kindly help me solve this problem. Sorry I am not a native english speaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood, you have a column which contains a string representing product's categories separated by comma. In this case you have to execute a substring function on the column `ProductCategoryID`, which is always discouraged.
I suggest you, instead of using the column `ProductTable.ProductCategoryID`, to make a link table `ProductsCategories` with the columns `ProductID, CategoryID`.

```
----------------------
| ProductsCategories |
----------------------
| ProductID          |
| CategoryID         |
----------------------
```

In this way you can use a more efficient QUERY like this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductTable.*
FROM ProductTable
    INNER JOIN ProductsCategories ON (ProductsCategories.ProductID = ProductTable.ProductID)
WHERE CategoryID IN
(
    SELECT CategoryID
    FROM ProductsCategories
    WHERE ProductID != ProductTable.ProductID
)
;
```

All this, of course, has sense if I've understood in the right way the structure of `ProductCategoryID` column :)